# Problems formatting trailing zeroes to specific decimal places

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having some difficulty with the format-number function.

Given this XML

```
<testvalues>
    <test value="02.25"/>
    <test value="02.2"/>
    <test value="02.20"/>
</testvalues>
```

I am trying to produce this output

```
<testvalues>
    <test>02.25</test>
    <test>02.2</test>
    <test>02.20</test>
</testvalues>
```

But I can't find a picture-string do do that.

Given this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="testvalues">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="by-1d"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="by-1plus1d"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="by-2d"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="test" mode="by-1d">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@value,'00.0')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test" mode="by-1plus1d">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@value,'00.0#')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="test" mode="by-2d">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@value,'00.00')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output created is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testvalues>
    <test>02.2</test>
    <test>02.2</test>
    <test>02.2</test>

    <test>02.25</test>
    <test>02.2</test>
    <test>02.2</test>

    <test>02.25</test>
    <test>02.20</test>
    <test>02.20</test>
</testvalues>
```

The trailing zeros do not match the the incoming digits.

- '00.00' will force 2 trailing digit
- '00.0' will trim to one trailing digit
- '00.0#' will force 2 digits **except** where 2nd digit is zero when it trims to 1 digit

I want to print just 1 trailing digit where the input is 1 trailing digit, but 2 digits (including zero) where the input has >1 trailing digit.

Is that possible?

Comment: Isn't the required output same as input?

Comment: Once converted to `xs:double`, 2.2, 2.20, and 02.20 are indistinguishable; if you want the output to depend on the lexical form of the input, rather than on its numeric value, then it seems to me you are looking at string manipulation, not at numeric formatting, for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print just 1 trailing digit where the input is 1 trailing digit, but 2 digits (including zero) where the input has >1 trailing digit.

To do *exactly* that, you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@value, if(string-length(substring-after(@value, '.')) > 1) then'00.00' else '00.0')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Given the input of:

**XML**

```
<testvalues>
    <test value="02"/>
    <test value="02.2"/>
    <test value="02.20"/>
    <test value="02.200"/>
    <test value="02.2000"/>
    <test value="02.20002"/>
</testvalues>
```

this would produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testvalues>
   <test>02.0</test>
   <test>02.2</test>
   <test>02.20</test>
   <test>02.20</test>
   <test>02.20</test>
   <test>02.20</test>
</testvalues>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbBfrFy/2

Comment: Obvious when you think about it. Thanks muchly!